# laravel image not found in public/storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-storage

I am trying to access images for my project.

I have run php artisan storage link

Laravel create public/storage

when I upload image to storage/app, I see the image in storage/app but not in public/storage.

When I try to view image on browser, I get error 404

controller.php

```
Property::create([
'SittingRoom'=> request()->file('sittingroom')->store('apartments')
]);
```

bladeview.php

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$duplex->SittingRoom)}}">
```

browswer link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/apartments/HNLDysVUdRG7ZTBkF2qFGk2B2tAKYzYcVImNEWLx.jpg
```

after running artisan storage link

C:\xampp\htdocs\OPAAM> php artisan storage:link

INFO  The [C:\xampp\htdocs\OPAAM\public\storage] link has been connected to [C:\xampp\htdocs\OPAAM\storage\app/public].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that in **`config/filesystems.php`**

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),
```

but in the **`.env`** file

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
```

This configuration saves your images in `Storage/app` instead of `storage/app/public`.

Images saved in `storage/app` cannot be accessed publicly.
So you have to change the **`.env`** file